# Generate script with INSERT SELECT statements from T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, database-migration

I have two databases in SQL Server 2014 Express, since a few days ago I am unifying both databases in such a way that there is only one left.

When I have this new database I must pass it to Azure (I don't have any experience using this technology), however, I am doing tests on my local server, so far I have created the whole scheme but I must fill out all the tables to perform tests with my application.

There are *313* tables of which many have more than *200,000* records, my question is, what is the best way to populate the database?

Because at this moment I want to test my local machine, I could fill in the tables through *Tasks> Generate Script> Advanced Options (Include only data)* but this information will change the day when the migration to Azure is done, therefore I must Do the same process.

So, is it possible to create an `INSERT SELECT` script so that it does not include records one by one and is as dynamic as possible? For example, you would have to generate an INSERT INTO similar to this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SchemaX].[TableA] ON ; 

INSERT INTO [SchemaX].[TableA]
           (
            [id]
           ,[fieldA]
           ,[fieldB]
           ,[fieldC])
SELECT
            [id]
           ,[fieldA]
           ,[fieldB]
           ,[fieldC]
FROM [server].[dbname].[SchemaX].[TableA]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SchemaX].[TableA] OFF ;
```

Some tables have `IDENTITY` enabled so you would have to recognize which tables are like this and use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` when inserting. This way you would have to link the production server and insert the information into the local server.

If there are suggestions or recommendations about another way you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490475/65706) before ...

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[procUtils_GenerateInsertProc]    Script Date: 03/20/2010 13:06:13 ******/
        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[procUtils_GenerateInsertProc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[procUtils_GenerateInsertProc]
    GO

    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[procUtils_GenerateInsertProc]    Script Date: 03/20/2010 13:06:13 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    --exec procUtils_GenerateInsertProc 'Whatever'  
    --exec sp_HelpText procUtils_GenerateInsertProc   
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procUtils_GenerateInsertProc]        
    @TableName [varchar](50)        
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER        
    AS        
    BEGIN -- proc start                                                            
    SET NOCOUNT ON;                                                            
    BEGIN TRY        --begin try                                                  
    --FIRST SEARCH THE TABLE WHICH HAD A "Feature" in its name                                 
    --SELECT NAME FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%Feature%'                                
    --SELECT column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Feature'              --SELECT *     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Task'                          

    --Decalre a variable to remember the position of the current delimiter                           
    DECLARE @ProcName varchar(1000)             
    set @ProcName = '[dbo].[procGen_' + @TableName + '_Insert]'            

    DECLARE @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar INT                                     
    DECLARE @PkColumnName varchar(200)          
    --Decalre a variable to remember the number of rows in the table                                 
    DECLARE @Count INT                                    
    DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(300);                                    
    DECLARE @DataType varchar(50)                          
    DECLARE @IsNullable bit    
    DECLARE @MaxLength INT            
    DECLARE @IsComputed BIT
    set @IsComputed = 0     
    DECLARE @IsPrimaryKey BIT
    set @IsPrimaryKey = 0     
    DECLARE @CODESTR VARCHAR(max)             
    --PRINT DROP PROCEDURE    
    set @CODESTR = ' ' 

    --Declare the Table variable                                     
    DECLARE @ColumnNames TABLE                                    
    (                                    
    Number INT IDENTITY(1,1), --Auto incrementing Identity column    
    TableName varchar(300) , --the name of the table    
    ColumnName VARCHAR(300) , --The string value                        ,             
    DataType varchar(50) ,  --the datatype                           
    IsNullable bit , --should we add =null in front             
    MaxLength INT        , --VARCHAR(LENGHTi)    
    IsComputed bit ,  --whether or not this table is computed    
    IsPrimaryKey bit --whether or not this table is computed    
    )                                    
    --Populate the TABLE variable using some logic                                    
    -- SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS                                 
    INSERT INTO @ColumnNames             
    (  
    TableName ,   
    ColumnName ,   
    DataType ,   
    IsNullable ,   
    MaxLength ,           
    IsComputed , 
    IsPrimaryKey )  
    SELECT   
    TableName ,   
    ColumnName ,   
    DataType ,  
    IsNullable ,   
    MaxLength ,   
    IsComputed   , 
    IsPrimaryKey
    from viewMeta_TableColumns   
    --debug where TableName = 'Whatever'  
    where TableName = @TableName  
    --SELECT column_name ,  Data_type , IsNullable , MaxLength            
    --from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS                                 
    --where TABLE_NAME=@TableName                                    
    --Initialize the looper variable                                    
    SET @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = 1                                    
    --Determine the number of rows in the Table                                    
    SELECT @Count=max(Number) from @ColumnNames                                    
    --A variable to hold the currently selected value from the table                                    
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR +  'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @ProcName + ''') IS NOT NULL            
    BEGIN             
    DROP PROC ' + @ProcName + '             
    END             
    GO'            
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '                          
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure ' + @ProcName + '*/            
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON            
    GO            
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON            
    GO            
    CREATE PROCEDURE ' + @ProcName + '            
    @CurUserSessionId [int] ,            
    @CurPageTypeId [int] ,            
    @MsgOut [varchar](200) OUTPUT ,            
    @DebugMsgOut [varchar](200) OUTPUT,            
    @Ret [int] OUTPUT ,' + CHAR(13)            
    --@COLUMN_NAME [DATA_TYPE] (MAX_LENGTH) =NULL ,             
    WHILE @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <= @Count --1st loop         
    BEGIN                                    

    --Load current value from the Table                                    
    SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar            
    SELECT @DataType = DataType FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                   
    SELECT @MaxLength = MaxLength FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                        
    set @IsNullable = ( select  IsNullable FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar  )
    set @IsPrimaryKey = ( select IsPrimaryKey FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                        )


    if ( @DataType = 'timestamp' or @IsComputed = 1) 
    begin 
    set @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar + 1
    continue    
    end 
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '@' + @ColumnName + ' ['+ @DataType +  '] '            
    --ADD THE (200)            
    IF @MaxLength IS NOT NULL             
    BEGIN --IF @MaxLength IS NOT NULL             
    --xml            
    if @DataType <> 'xml' and @DataType <> 'sql_variant' and 
    @DataType <> 'text' and @DataType <> 'ntext' and @DataType <> 'image' and 
    @DataType <> 'hierarchyid' and @DataType <> 'bit' and @DataType <> 'varbinary'  and
    @DataType <> 'int' and @DataType <> 'uniqueidentifier' and @DataType <> 'tinyint' and 
    @DataType <> 'timestamp' and @DataType <> 'uniqueidentifier' and @DataType <> 'smallint' and 
    @DataType <> 'bigint' and @DataType <> 'smallmoney' and @DataType <> 'money' and 
    @DataType <> 'real' and @DataType <> 'smalldatetime' and @DataType <> 'datetime' 


    begin --those with()            

    if @MaxLength <> -1          
    SET @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR , @MaxLength ) + ')'               
    else           
    SET @CODESTR =    @CODESTR + '(max)'               
    end --those with(200)            
    else             
    begin             
    SET @CODESTR =  @CODESTR             --DO NOTHING
    end               
    END --IF @MaxLength IS NOT NULL             

    IF @IsNullable = 1            
    SET @CODESTR = + @CODESTR + ' = NULL '            

    if @IsPrimaryKey = 1           
    SET @CODESTR = @CODESTR + ' OUTPUT '           

    if @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <> @Count             
    SET @CODESTR = @CODESTR + ','            

    --DEBUGGING            
    --set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '@ColumnName - ' + @ColumnName             
    --set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '@DataType - ' + @DataType                      
    --set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '@IsNullable - ' + @IsNullable             
    --set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '@MaxLength - ' +  CONVERT ( VARCHAR , @MaxLength )            
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + CHAR(13)

    SET @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar + 1       
    END                                   
    SET @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '          
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER              
    AS              
    BEGIN -- proc start                                          
    SET NOCOUNT ON;                                          
    BEGIN TRY        --begin try                                   
    --                
    set @Ret = 1 --assume false from the beginning                 
    declare @MsgKey [nvarchar](max)      
    declare @MsgTxt [nvarchar](max)         
    exec procUtils_GetMsgTxtByKeyAndUserSessionId      
    @UserSessionId =2 ,       
    @MsgKey = ''MsgOkTheAddingOfItemIsOk'' ,       
    @MsgTxt =  ''''      
    set @MsgOut = replace (@MsgTxt , ''{0}'' , ''' + @TableName + '''  )      
    declare @thisProcName varchar(300)                
    set @thisProcName= ( SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))                        
    '          
    SET @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = 1              --START LOOP AGAIN             
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR +  '      
    --Action !!!      
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @TableName + ']( ' + CHAR(13)                                    
    --Loop through until all row processing is done                                    
    WHILE @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <= @Count     --2nd loop            
    BEGIN                                    

    --Load current value from the Table                                    
    SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar            
    SELECT @DataType = DataType FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                   
    SELECT @MaxLength = MaxLength FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                        
    set @IsNullable = ( select  IsNullable FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar  )
    set @IsPrimaryKey = ( select IsPrimaryKey FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                        )


    if   @IsPrimaryKey = 1          
    begin -- the primary key           
    set @PkColumnName = @ColumnName          
    end --the primary key           

    if ( @DataType = 'timestamp' or @IsComputed = 1 or @IsPrimaryKey = 1 ) 
    begin 
    set @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar + 1
    continue    
    end 


    --select 
    if @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <= @Count  
    BEGIN
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '[' + @ColumnName + ']' --null the codestring var            
    if @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <> @Count  
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + ',  --type of ' + @DataType   + CHAR(13) --WITH COMMA
    ELSE 
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + ' --type of ' + @DataType   + CHAR(13) --NO COMMA
    END -- IF SHOULD PRINT COLUMN 

    SET @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar + 1;                             

    END --eof while 2
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR +  ') VALUES ( '
    --AND START ALL OVER AGAIN                               
    SET @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = 1                          
    --Loop through until all row processing is done                    

    WHILE @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <= @Count --WHILE 3            
    BEGIN                                    

    --Load current value from the Table                                    
    SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar            
    SELECT @DataType = DataType FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                   
    SELECT @MaxLength = MaxLength FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                        
    set @IsNullable = ( select  IsNullable FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar  )
    set @IsPrimaryKey = ( select IsPrimaryKey FROM @ColumnNames             
    WHERE Number = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar                        )

    if ( @DataType = 'timestamp' or @IsComputed = 1 or @IsPrimaryKey = 1) 
    begin 
    set @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar + 1
    continue    
    end 

    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + '@' + @ColumnName 

    if @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <= @Count     
    BEGIN

    IF @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar <> @Count  
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + ' , --type of ' + @DataType  --all others with comma
    else
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + ' --type of ' + @DataType  --the last one without comma

    END -- IF SHOULD NOT PRINT COLUMN 
    --increase the counter 
    set @CODESTR = @CODESTR + CHAR(13)
    SET @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar = @CurrentDelimiterPositionVar + 1;                                    
    END                                                           
    set nocount off                                 
    SET @CODESTR = @CODESTR +  ')            
    SET @' + @pkColumnName + ' = @@IDENTITY          
    set @Ret = @@ERROR                
    set @DebugMsgOut = ''TODO:REMOVE INSERT OK ''              
    END TRY                 
    BEGIN CATCH                                        
    EXEC @ret = [dbo].[procUtils_GetMsgTxtByKeyAndUserSessionId]                
    @UserSessionId = 2,                
    @MsgKey = N''ErrorMsgMenuRetrievalFailed'',                
    @MsgTxt = @MsgOut OUTPUT                
    set @ret = 1                                  
    set @msgOut = @MsgTxt      
    set @debugMsgOut = '' Error number: '' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS varchar(100)) +                               
    ''Error message: '' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ''Error severity: '' +                 
    CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS varchar(10)) +                               
    ''Error state: '' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS varchar(100)) +                 
    ''XACT_STATE: '' + CAST(XACT_STATE() AS varchar(100))                                        
    -- record the error in the database                                        
    set @debugMsgOut = @debugMsgOut + @msgOut                            
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[LogStore] ( [Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message])                
    values ( getdate() , N''8'', N''DEBUG'', @thisProcName , @debugMsgOut )                
    END CATCH                                        
    END --procedure end               
    GO             
    '                          
    print @codestr

    END TRY        --end try                                                  
    BEGIN CATCH                                                        
    print ' Error number: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS varchar(100)) +                                               
    'Error message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + 'Error severity: ' +                                 
    CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS varchar(1000)) +                                
    'Error state: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS varchar(100)) +                                 
    'XACT_STATE: ' + CAST(XACT_STATE() AS varchar(100))                                                        
    END CATCH                                                        
    END --procedure end                                                             
    --USE [Gaf]                                
    --GO                                
    --SELECT NAME FROM SYS.tables where name like '%Msg%'                                
    --EXEC [dbo].[procUtils_GenerateInsertProc] @TableName = N'Whatever'

    GO
```

Comment: Does this code generate a procedure for each table? I wonder if you have the complete code because some procedures like `procUtils_GetMsgTxtByKeyAndUserSessionId` are not defined, I had to look for the `viewMeta_TableColumns` view on the same website

Comment: yes it does ... you don't actually need this procUtils_GetMsgTxtByKeyAndUserSessionId it just a msg fetching proc .. and forgot the view , sorry ... the code is about 10 years old ...